# Windows service cannot be killed

Tags: windows

I've got a service that needs to be resarted, but all attempts to kill it fail.

I have tried everything i've found online and nothing has seemed to work.

The core issue seems to be that Services is holding onto the process and not allowing it to be killed

```
    ERROR: The process with PID 11204 (child process of PID 572) could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
```

this happens when i try to force kill the task using taskkill/f /pid 11204 /t
PID 572 is services, so i cannot kill it without crashing windows.

There is also an Interactive Services detection that is activating but just leads to a blank screen i can't exit out of (since the process is dead) but turning this off still doesn't allow me to kill it.

I've found similar issues around but none seem to have the problem of the program being a child of services, and so can't kill the parent.

Is a system restart the ONLY option here? This is a production server and so restarting has to be done only at scheduled downtime, so looking for other options.

Answer (score -1):

Services should be controlled via services APIs, or `SC`command-line tool. Try `SC stop` command.

---

On a call to `ControlService[Ex]` with `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP`, explicitly from your SW or from `SC` tool, service's `Handler[Ex]` should receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP`. At this point service should

- Stop all its own started threads and free its own allocated resources

  - If it takes long, should also call `SetServiceStatus` with `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` before that
- Call `SetServiceStatus` with `SERVICE_STOPPED` to inform the system that is is no longer running
- Return from `Handler[Ex]`

If the service was the only service in its process, `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` is likely to return shortly, and at this point service process should exit. If there are other services in the process, `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` will not return, and process should not exit, but the service being stopped is considered stopped anyway.

Comment: Stopping the service doesn't respond. After a long delay of it attempting to stop it, it eventually errors with a timeout. Eventually it will let you "Start" the interface again, but the process is still stuck in the process list and cannot be killed. Starting the service again doesn't really help as the previous is still tying up the ports it's supposed to be using.

Comment: Attach a debugger to the service and see why it's not responding to the shutdown control event. I'm assuming you wrote the service, seeing as you wrote "I've got a service", and this is a computer programming site.

Comment: The service is created by a colleague in a language i'm not familiar with (Clarion). Not even sure what kind of software they use as a debugger.They seemed just as stumped.

Comment: It is debugging problem, so you have to debug it. Use WinDbg and debug assembly if the language implementation compiles binary, but doesn't have a good debugger. Use text debugging `OutputDebugString` or text log file if you cannot debug step with a debugger. I've added some details on how should service stopping work.